# Time delay in Matlab for a specific function, while letting the rest of the functions run

Tags: multithreading, matlab

I am currently  working on an image processing object in Matlab. I am acquiring images from a webcam using the `snapshot` function, which are to be processed in various ways (irrelevant to the question).

I would like these snapshots to be acquired every 5 seconds. However, in these 5 seconds, I do not want my program to pause and wait, I want it to run the image processing functions. I have tried `pause`, but that obviously pauses the whole program. The way I imagine the processor circuitry from my basic IC knowledge, I am looking to implement an event coming from a clock counter, which would stop the machine instructions dealing with the image processing part, and prioritise the instructions involving the image acquisition.

I have stumbled on [this link](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/explicit-multi-threading-in-matlab-part1) that talks about multithreading in Matlab using Java.   Is there an easier way of implementing what I want to do?

Could you please suggest some functions that achieve what I want to do? If there is no function which does what I want, could you point me towards some articles or books which deal with the subject?

Comment: Spiking unnecessary context information (greetings, informations about yourself, ...) should improve your question and improve your chances to get good answers. Please take a moment to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the help center. Good luck and welcome.

Comment: I assume that your "image processing functions" take longer than 5 seconds to run for a given image? Also, you might check out the [`timer` class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html).

Comment: @horchler No, they do not..But I would like the snapshots to be taken every 5 seconds irrespective of the time the other functions take. I would like to treat the two as different tasks being done in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a timer object

```
rate=5; % call every 5 s
my_timer= timer('TimerFcn',{@my_timer_callback,arguments}, 'Period',    rate,'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate'); % specify arguments for additional arguments 
start(my_timer) % stop(my_timer) to end processing
```

and do the processing inside my_timer_callback.

```
function my_timer_callback(obj,event,arguments)
% do processing here
```

Better would be to run the callback triggered by the camera, so I would look into whether Matlab allows you to attach callbacks to the camera data acquisition (e.g. in the same way as for daq objects).